# Separating hyperplane minimization

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What algorithm would you use to find a separating hyperplane between two convex sets that **minimizes the sum of distances of all points (that are in those two sets) to the hyperplane**?

Comment: The "sum of distances of all points" needs to be clarified.  It cannot literally be a sum except in the trivial case of two convex sets that each are single points.  Possible you have in mind "summing" by integration, but it would improve the Question to give or illustrate such an approach with formulas and an example.

Comment: An algorithm needs algorithmic operators. What is available in your case? The projection operators onto each of the two sets (in which case I assume that the sets are also closed)?